# Box2D World.destroyBody Being Really Buggy

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a character that shoots when a button is pressed. When the bullet hits a wall or an enemy it should be destroyed. My issue is that sometime the bullet won't be destroyed when it hits a wall and that will cause or sorts of things to go wrong. Any way to make it better?

EDIT: I realized the problem is that if the bullets take to long to reach the wall, it will destroy the new bullet instead of the one that just hit the wall. A temporary fix is to just make the character shoot slower so that no new bullet is created before the previous one hits the wall. Is there any better way to do this though?

This is the update method where I destroy the bullet or create a new one:

```
shootTimer += dt;
    if(setToDestroy){
        world.destroyBody(b2Body);
        setToDestroy = false;
    }
   else if(currentStateShooting == State.NORTH  && shootTimer >= SHOOT_WAIT_TIME){
        shootTimer = 0;
        defineBullet(isaac.ISAACX, isaac.ISAACY);
        b2Body.applyLinearImpulse(0, 3, b2Body.getWorldCenter().x, b2Body.getWorldCenter().y, true);
   }
```

This is the the worldContactListener method:

```
public class worldContactListener implements ContactListener {
@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

    int cDef = fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits | fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits;

    if("head".equals(fixA.getUserData()) || "head".equals(fixB.getUserData())){
        Fixture body = fixA.getUserData() == "head" ? fixA : fixB;
        Fixture object = body == fixA ? fixB : fixA;

        if(object.getUserData() != null && interactiveTileObject.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getUserData().getClass())){
            ((interactiveTileObject) object.getUserData()).onBodyHit();
        }
    }
    else if("body".equals(fixA.getUserData()) || "body".equals(fixB.getUserData())){
        Fixture body = fixA.getUserData() == "body" ? fixA : fixB;
        Fixture object = body == fixA ? fixB : fixA;

        if(object.getUserData() != null && interactiveTileObject.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getUserData().getClass())){
            ((interactiveTileObject) object.getUserData()).onBodyHit();
        }
    }


    switch (cDef) {
        case icsGame.BULLET_BIT | icsGame.ENEMY_BIT:
            if (fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits == icsGame.ENEMY_BIT) {
                ((enemy) fixA.getUserData()).hit();
                ((isaacHead) fixB.getUserData()).destroyBullet();
            } else if (fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits == icsGame.ENEMY_BIT) {
                ((enemy) fixB.getUserData()).hit();
                ((isaacHead) fixA.getUserData()).destroyBullet();
            }
            break;
        case icsGame.BULLET_BIT | icsGame.DEAFAULT_BIT:
            if (fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits == icsGame.BULLET_BIT) {
                ((isaacHead) fixA.getUserData()).destroyBullet();
            } else if (fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits == icsGame.BULLET_BIT) {
                ((isaacHead) fixB.getUserData()).destroyBullet();
            }
            break;
        case icsGame.ISAAC_BIT | icsGame.ENEMY_BIT:
            Gdx.app.log("ISAAC", "DIED");
            break;
        case icsGame.ENEMY_BIT | icsGame.DEAFAULT_BIT:
            if (fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits == icsGame.ENEMY_BIT) {
                ((enemy) fixA.getUserData()).reverseVelocity(true, true);
            } else if (fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits == icsGame.ENEMY_BIT) {
                ((enemy) fixB.getUserData()).reverseVelocity(true, true);
            }
            break;
        case icsGame.ENEMY_BIT | icsGame.ENEMY_BIT:
                ((enemy) fixA.getUserData()).reverseVelocity(true, false);
                ((enemy) fixB.getUserData()).reverseVelocity(true, false);
                break;
    }
}
```

And this is the destroyBullet method:

```
public void destroyBullet(){
    setToDestroy = true;
}
```